# Wrong happens unmarshaling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I can not understand why the unmarshaling.

Here is my class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "privileges")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public  class Privilege {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "number_residents")
    private Integer numberResidents;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "value")
    private String value;
    @XmlElement(name = "privilege")
    private String privilage;
```

below getters, setters, equals and toString
}

I'm trying to do unmarshalling.

```
 File file = new File( "response.xml");
                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Privilege.class);
                Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
                Privilege privilege = (Privilege) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
                System.out.println(privilege);
```

But I always get:

```
Privilege{numberResidents=null, value='null', privilage='Test privilege'}
```

But in a file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<privileges>
    <privilege number_residents="3" value="bb2">Test privilege</privilege>
</privileges>
```

I need your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping is incorrect.

Try :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "privileges")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Privileges {

    @XmlElement(name="privilege")
    private Privilege privilege;

    //Getters and setters

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Privilege{

    @XmlAttribute(name = "number_residents")
    private Integer numberResidents;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "value")
    private String value;
    @XmlValue
    private String privilege;

    //getters and setters

}
```